# When to add or omit hypen between word and number?

Tags: numbers, reformed-orthography, hyphen

I see in some texts a hypen `-`. Especially while expessing how old somebody is, or how outdated something is. I would like to know if there is a rule on how to use it?

> Die **5jährigen** Erzählerinnen leisten unter den Bedingungen der formellen Situation folglich strukturell mehr als unter den Bedingungen der informellen Situation.

Answer (score 8):

Duden is very clear on this:

The hyphen is correct according to Duden - Numbers in digits that are part of a concatenation have to be connected to the rest of the word using a hyphen.

> der 75-prozentige Rum
>
> die 12-jährige Tochter
>
> ein 12-Zylindermotor
>
> ein 8-tägiger Urlaub

Only if the number is connected to a postfix (Nachsilbe) that is not a valid word on its own, the hyphen is omitted:

> 1000stel
>
> 68er-Generation
>
> 20%iger Likör

According to this, your example is actually wrong.

Comment: See also § 40 (3) and § 41 of the official rules [here](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/regeln2006.pdf), [here](http://www.duden.de/sites/default/files/downloads/amtliche_Regelungen.pdf), or [here](http://canoo.net/services/GermanSpelling/Amtlich/Bindestrich/pgf40-45.html).

Comment: Scientific texts would require a space between *20* and *%*, since the latter is treated like a unit. However, that space is commonly omitted in everyday writing.

Comment: Just like in an example given in @Loong first link (§ 44), I would write *12-Zylinder-Motor*, because it's a *Motor* that has *12 Zylinder*, and not a *Zylindermotor* that is somehow 12-fold.

Comment: @Raketenolli - When I wrote that word, It was actually the single one where I was unsure - You might be correct we need the second hyphen.